# Actually playable games based on graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

In computer science lessons, we have recently got the task to program something using graphs. Due to my enthusiasm for computer games, i would really prefer to implement a concept for a game. The requirements for the project are:

- the underlying graph mustn't be necessarily planar and it would be better if it's not necessarily plain, too (so you can't simply implement tic-tac-toe for example)
- the underlying concept shouldn't be too hard to understand
- the game should be enjoyable to some extend
- it should be a one-player game

(but only the first requirement is *really* necessary)

So does anyone have an idea? I'm very grateful about any proposal!

Comment: You should look at some existing graph theory based game for inspiration. I consult the oracle google and she kindly points me to the [Icosian game](http://naturelovesmath-en.blogspot.hk/2011/01/icosian-graph-theory-game.html) and the [Shannon switching game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_switching_game) ( playable [here](http://www.games1729.com/graphg/) ).

Comment: Shannon Switching game is a good choice, and a special case of it, [Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29), has been well-studied; the Wikipedia page describes many variants.

Answer (score 3):

The game of [Sim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sim_%28pencil_game%29) is very playable and is pure graph theory.  The board consists of six dots. Two players, Red and Blue, take turns; a player's turn consists of  picking two points that are not already connected with a line, and connecting them with a line of that player's color.  A player who completes a triangle of their own color loses.

[A famous theorem of Ramsey theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers) states that the game of Sim cannot end in a tie; after 15 half-moves, the board is full and must contain a triangle of one player's color. (If the game is played on a board with only five dots, it can end in a tie.)

Answer (score 1):

You asked for one-player games; here's one: [Planarity](http://planarity.net/).  The game presents a planar graph, and the player's job is to find a planar embedding of the graph by rearranging its vertices.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giantllama.maps) is an Android game I made inspired by Hamilton's [Icosian game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian_game), where you must connect every node by visiting them only once. I used Mathematica to generate planar graphs that have only one solution, and then a custom software to turn the graph into a map by representing nodes as regions (or "villages") and edges as borders between regions.

The first few levels are pretty easy but it gets harder as you progress, although I unfortunately hit a limit on the number of "regions" you can fit inside a phone screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting game, note that you can replace the hexagon with any other $n$-gon, you just need to keep two nodes on each of its edges with only one edge being connected to each node inside 1 $n$-gon. You can also make other generalizations etc.

http://entanglement.gopherwoodstudios.com/en-US-index.html

Comment: سلام امیر حسین. خوبی؟

Answer (score 0):

Though I question the on-topicness of this question, how about [9 men's morris?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Men's_Morris)

I love this game and used to play it all the time. It's also generalizable to $n$ men's morris on various sized boards which might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you are searching, but very interesting: the game [Sprouts](http://nrich.maths.org/1208).

> The game starts by drawing three dots.
>
> ...
>
> The first player has a turn by joining two of the dots and marking a new dot in the middle of the line. Or the line may start and end on the same dot.
>
> ...
>
> When drawing a line, it cannot cross another line. (This is important to remember!)
> A dot cannot have more than three lines branching to or from it.
>
> ...